# Vuejs charts not working until refreshing the page

Tags: vue.js, chart.js, vuetify.js, single-page-application, lifecycle

I'm working on a single page application that has different modules for different clients, the app starts off in a main module and then I have to change the module to a specific client to see the charts, since they're the only ones that need it.

I dispatch the API that brings me the data to fill the charts on the created hook, and when I go to the clients module the charts are there but they have no data. In other to see the data I have to reload the page, which is a pain to do everytime, what can I do to see the data right away?

My created hook:

```
 async created () {
    if (this.selectedApp.UUID) {
      await this.$store.dispatch('getAppsStatistics')
      await this.$store.dispatch('getCountExtradata', 'Nombre de la propiedad')
      await this.callDropdownItems()
    }
  },
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: They actually have no data or they are not rerendered after daa received?

Comment: @TJ I'm sorry, at the moment I can't provide a reproducible example since the code is from work.

Comment: @VladimirShefer Answering the second question, they are not receiving the data until I refresh the page, the graph space appears empty, with no bars

Comment: is it because this.selectedApp.UUID is null or undefined. so the code block inside is not triggered in the first place until you refresh the page? Can you confirm the the code block inside the if statement can be accessed in first render?

Comment: @MicFung The code is hidden if you're not in the clients app that has it, as soon as you access it the code block is shown, it shows the grid where the graph should be, just no bars!

Comment: I know there is no bars shown. but the bar data should be retrieved after `dispatch('getAppsStatistics')` and `dispatch('getCountExtradata'`, right?
What i mean is can you confirm the dispatch methods are called in the first place?

Comment: @MicFung Sorry for the confusion, the dispatch method is being called on created hook, but the results array is empty, as soon as i refresh it shows data

Comment: Sorry to ask so much questions and ask you to do some obvious things because there is little information and we can only imagine all the possible cases. How about comment the `if (this.selectedApp.UUID) {` line to have a test. I would like to double confirm the await functions are called right away.

Comment: @MicFung seems like its the same, I think that because the field that populates the chart doesn't exist on the first app its just not parsing it correctly as soon as I change the app

Comment: No error in the console if there is no bar chart? which chart library are you using?

Comment: @MicFung no errors! the call is successful, is just not providing the right field to populate on create. I'm using chartjs

Comment: where are the `mapState({ })` exist?, is it in the `computed` block?

Comment: @MicFung It does and it is!

Comment: Have you read about it ? https://vue-chartjs.org/guide/#updating-charts 
You can try the method the doc provided.  I don't have time to make a mock to test. Maybe someone can help here.